# Why do comments to deleted answers not show up in the activity log?

Tags: feature-request, recent-activity

Why do comments to deleted answers not show up in the activity log?

For example, my comments to an answer to
[What exactly is a linear space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/547018/what-exactly-is-a-linear-space)
don't show up in https://math.stackexchange.com/users/27978/copper-hat?tab=activity.

It is certainly not a big deal, but sometimes I use the activity log to track down a thread of conversation or a particular topic, and was surprised that some activity was pruned unexpectedly.

Comment: The deleted answer doesn't seem to show up on the poster's activity log either.  I imagine deleting removes the answer and all associated comments from the activity logs of all parties.  You could tag this with feature-request if you would like to see this be changed.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber: Good suggestion. If it was intended, I was wondering what the intent was.

Comment: I'd like to see this as well. Something like the flagging history would work for me -- a red backdrop when the post has been deleted.